# In Batch Script, Extract String from a XML

Tags: windows, powershell, batch, batch-file

I'm new to batch scripting.

I'm trying to extract the status from a XML output.
Basically I need appPoolState from below, if it's "Started".

```
<output>
    <MSDeploy.recycleApp>
        <recycleApp path="Default Web Site" isDest="False" recycleMode="RecycleAppPool" appPool="DefaultAppPool" appPoolState="Started" workerProcesses="0" />
    </MSDeploy.recycleApp>
</output>
```

Based on my google searches I've tried below code. And I'm able to extract the status.

But I think there could be a simplified version of this.
Or probably a different approach that is better than this?

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims=<>" %%i in ('findstr "appPoolState=" msdeploy.xml') do set FL1=%%i
echo %FL1%

for /f "tokens=8 delims= " %%a in ("%FL1%") do (
  set FL2=%%a
)
echo %FL2%
for /f "tokens=2 delims=\= " %%a in ("%FL2%") do (
  set FL3=%%a
)
echo %FL3%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `=` character with `"` as a delimiter, in token 10 you can extract your desired string:

In command line:

```bat
for /F tokens^=10delims^=^=^"  %i in ('findstr appPoolState^= msdeploy.xml')do echo\%~i
```

In bat/cmd file:

```bat
for /F tokens^=10delims^=^=^"  %%i in ('findstr appPoolState^= msdeploy.xml')do echo\%%~i
```

- Understand that this forces you to work on tokens and delimiters without double quotes, which is why you have `^=` in tokens, and `^=^=^"` in delimiters, also, you can use one additional `^` after `tokens^=10`and before delimiters: `tokens^=10^delims^=^=^"`

```bat
@echo off 

for /F tokens^=10^delims^=^=^" %%i in ('findstr appPoolState^= msdeploy.xml')do set "_FL1=%%~i"

echo=%_FL1%
```

- Output results:

```bat
Started
```

---

---

- To do the same in PowerShell:

```bat
$str=Get-Content .\msdeploy.xml | foreach-object  {$_.split('""')[9]} 
$str
```

- Or using aliases:

```bat
$str=cat msdeploy.xml | % {$_.split('""')[9]} 
$str
```

- For one line:

```bat
$str=Get-Content .\msdeploy.xml| foreach-object  {$_.split('""')[9]}; $str
```

- For one line using aliases:

```bat
$str=cat msdeploy.xml|% {$_.split('""')[9]}; $str
```

- Output results is the same from bat/cmd code.

```bat
Started
```

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[Set](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**

  [√] **[For](https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html)**

  [√] **[For /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**

  [√] **[Findstr](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)**

  [√] **[Split  (Refer: `PowerShell`)](https://ss64.com/ps/split.html)**

  [√] **[Get-Content | cat (Refer: `PowerShell`)](https://ss64.com/ps/get-content.html)**

  [√] **[Foreach-Object | % (Refer: `PowerShell`)](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)**

---

Comment: Wow, that's perfect.
I'll definitely make use of those documentation, thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

Since you listed ***[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)*** in your tags, here is a **`.PS1`** way to get the info. [*grin*]

What it does ...

- creates a multiline string to work on
  when ready to use real data, replace the entire `#region/#endregion` block with whatever method you use to get the string.
- Converts the string to an object using the `[xml]` type accelerator
- Navigates into the resulting object to get the desired property & its value
- Displays that on screen

The code ...

```
#region >>> create a multiline string
#    in real life, use your source method
$InString = @'
<output>
    <MSDeploy.recycleApp>
        <recycleApp path="Default Web Site" isDest="False" recycleMode="RecycleAppPool" appPool="DefaultAppPool" appPoolState="Started" workerProcesses="0" />
    </MSDeploy.recycleApp>
</output>
'@
#endregion >>> create a multiline string

$XmlInString = [xml]$InString
$AppPoolState = $XmlInString.output.'MSDeploy.recycleApp'.recycleApp.appPoolState

$AppPoolState
```

- Output = **`Started`**

Answer (score 0):

To grab a specific value, replace `appPoolState` with the attribute (eg. `workerProcesses`)

```dos
@echo off
====SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

set "appPoolState="
FOR /F delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ('find "appPoolState=" ^<example.xml') do (
    set "line=%%L"
    set "line=!line:*appPoolState=!"
    FOR %%V in (!line!) do set "appPoolState=%%~V"&goto :escape
)
:escape
echo(!appPoolState!
```

---

It uses the *[starred substring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28114012/12861751) and jump to a label to escape the `FOR` loop.